# Has the following problem posed by Deligne in the official description of the Hodge conjecture been solved?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Towards the end of his [official description of the Hodge conjecture](http://www.claymath.org/sites/default/files/hodge.pdf), Deligne asked the following question:

> Let $A$ be an abelian variety over the algebraic closure $\mathbb{F}$
>   of a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$. Lift $A$ in two different ways to
>   characteristic $0$, to complex abelian varieties $A_1$ and $A_2$
>   defined over $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$. Pick Hodge classes $\mathfrak{z}_1$
>   and $\mathfrak{z}_2$ on $A_1$ and $A_2$, of complementary dimension.
>   Interpreting $\mathfrak{z}_1$ and $\mathfrak{z}_2$ as $\ell$-adic
>   cohomology classes, one can define the intersection number $\kappa$ of the reduction of $\mathfrak{z}_1$ and $\mathfrak{z}_2$ over
>   $\mathbb{F}$. Is $\kappa$ a rational number?

Has this problem been solved?