# Is computing $\ell$-adic intersection number feasible?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

This question was inspired by [ [Has the following problem posed by Deligne in the official description of the Hodge conjecture been solved?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/245364/has-the-following-problem-posed-by-deligne-in-the-official-description-of-the-ho) ] (which did not get any reply). I am curious if *testing* (not proving) this conjecture stated by Deligne is currently possible. Assuming that we have two explicitly given  abelian varieties over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ possessing Hodge classes and with the same reduction to $\mathbb{F}_q$, is computing the  intersection number of the reduced l-adic cohomology classes with sufficient precision feasible using existing methods? (*A priori* this intersection number belongs to $\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}$, and according to the conjecture it must be rational.)

Comment: What does ``sufficient precision" mean? Say we can compute them mod $\ell^n$. We have evidence for the conjecture if the residue class contains a rational number of height much less than $\ell^{n/2}$, but since every residue class contains a rational number of height at most $\ell^{n/2}$, we can never disprove the conjecutre Unless, I guess, we have a bound on what the numerator and denominator of the rational number should be?

Comment: My (not very educated) opinion is that the conjecture is more likely to be true then false. And, my wild guess is that $l^{100}$ or at least  $l^{1000}$  should be enough to see the number unless the variety is not very nice.  Of course, a much more interesting possibility is disproving the conjecture (and collecting $1M). But yes,  one cannot  do it this way  having  no rigorous bound on the height, and obtaining the latter may be rather difficult.